# In chrome, swf can not run

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash, debugging

swf code, and file name is test.swf:

```
function test() {
    trace('this is a test');
}
test();
```

I visit it by http://localhost/test.swf
but I get nothing in window.

```
chrome version: 46.0.2490.86 m

chrome:plugin
Adobe Flash Player - version： 19.0.0.245
Shockwave Flash 19.0 r0
```

Comment: trace statements will not show up unless running in a debug player attached to something with an output window.   If you have FlashPro or other flash ide installed,  use the flash debug player in your browser, then do remote debugging to debug the browser swf in your ide.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are unclear on what [trace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#trace()) does in ActionScript.

While some languages have a `print` or `echo` type command, AS does not.

`trace()` is for debugging, to send a message to the output panel when your code is running in the debug flash player.

So with the code you've shown, the expected result is a blank screen as the code doesn't do anything that affects the screen.

If you want to put text on the screen, you'd have to do the following:

```
function test():void {
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.text = "this is a test";
    addChild(tf);
}

test();
```

If you want to use trace statements in the browser for debugging, you'll have to install the [flash debug player](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) for your browser.

Once installed, you can [start a remote debug session in FlashPro](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html#debug_a_remote_actionscript_3_0_swf_file).

Comment: thanks. I use your code in test.swf, but I also can nothing. what's wrong?

Comment: you need to provide more information.  Share your fla, swf and html page.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial for making textFields to hold visible text within your SWF.

**[Textfield tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/)**

Alternatively if you want something like a browser alert/pop-up then try

**[Javascript Alert from AS3 tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/flash/calling_javascript_flash_using_as3.htm)**